# How to iterate structures properly

Tags: javascript, screeps

I'd like to iterate found structures but I don't know what way is the best for this.

I've tried this one:

```
for (var ext in creep.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION }})){
    console.log(ext.energy);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

So for now I'm using an approach that works, but it looks ugly:

```
for(var i = 0; i < creep.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION }}).length; i++) {
    var ext = creep.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION }})[i];
    console.log(ext.energy);
}
```

I'm not sure, maybe this is a question related to js. I'm a completely newbie in js. Can you advice about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ext` contains the key, not the value of the result.

So what I have done, is move the results out of the loop and put in a variable called `results`. That way, I have a variable to reference to in the loop.

So whats going on is that, because the `ext` in your code is storing the key, which is a string type value. Its returning the results from the string object, you're doing something like `"key".energy` and that returns the value `undefined`, because the String object doesn't have a key like that.

So here below is the code that should work:

```
var results = creep.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, {filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION }});
for (var ext in results){
    console.log(results[ext].energy);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use Game.structures to iterate over one's own structures. It's probably quicker than doing a room.find() which is marked as an average CPU using function.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm feeling like to dig into such things... even though iterating over Game.structures is a smaller list, the expand rate is linear and code is executed pretty quickly. Also, the more I hear about these things, the more I actually prefer to a) use your own code or b) demand for a better screeps api.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can also use `Array.forEach` function and arrow functions notation!

```
creep.room.find(FIND_MY_STRUCTURES, { filter: { structureType: STRUCTURE_EXTENSION } })
    .forEach((ext) => { console.log(ext.energy); });
```